# How do I load to default website when inactive

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am trying to do a `WebView` that surf websites. When the program is inactive for few seconds, the `WebView`will load back to the beginning of the website.

JavaFXApplication13.java

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();        
    Duration duration = Duration.seconds(10);
    PauseTransition transition = new PauseTransition(duration);
    transition.setOnFinished(evt -> inactive());
    stage.addEventFilter(InputEvent.ANY, evt -> transition.playFromStart());
    transition.play();
}

private void inactive(){
    //to investigate if it inactive
    System.out.println("Inactive once");   
    //load other website when inactive ?

}
```

MainController.java

```
@FXML
WebView webview;
private WebEngine webEngine;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    webEngine = webview.getEngine();
    webview.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
    webEngine.load("http://www.google.com");}
```

This is my main.fxml
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_WnWhkbjaX1s2Y2jI0ojIvc2aQC1njJh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access the `webview` from the `controller`

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();

MainController controller = loader.getController();
controller.loadDefaultSite();
```

And in the `MainController` make a Function

```
public void loadDefaultSite() {
    webEngine.load("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Example:

```
private MainController controller;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    controller = loader.getController();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();        
    Duration duration = Duration.seconds(10);
    PauseTransition transition = new PauseTransition(duration);
    transition.setOnFinished(evt -> inactive());
    stage.addEventFilter(InputEvent.ANY, evt -> transition.playFromStart());
    transition.play();
}

private void inactive(){
   //check if site is already default... 
   controller.loadDefaultSite();

}
```

Comment: It does works. Thank you